# Is it possible to get the line/character number of an event target/srcElement?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently checking for right-clicks using oncontextmenu as such:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    ...
}
```

I know how to get the target HTML, but I want to know how to find the position of the target element in the HTML. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by position? in pixels?

Comment: In characters or lines. Take `<p>Lorem ipsum</p>`, for example. When I find that the selected element is this, I want to know where in the HTML it is located, either in characters or lines. So in a full HTML file that would probably be hundreds of characters or tens of lines in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html

var element = $0;( Returns Selected root element in DOM)

Answer (score 0):

This might work, it will however return an incorrect value if any preceding elements are identical to the target

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
    var charPos = document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(e.target.outerHTML);
}
```